# На странице смены пароля не переведён текст

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, способы-входа

На [странице настроек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current) нажать на смену пароля.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня по ссылке открывается просто главная. Наверное из-за авторизации через сторонний сервис.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да, там странности какие-то. Нужно со страницы переходить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11582

> Текущий пароль

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11570

> Новый пароль

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11569

> Новый пароль (ещё раз)